# cllocationmanager returns latitude and longitude of zero in the first couple of seconds. How can I

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocation

My app has a table view that loads faster than the cllocationmanager instance initializes (At least that's my suspicion), and in the first couple of seconds of runtime cllocation returns both langitude and latitude of zero. What should I do in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why is the (0, 0) coordinate invalid for your use case?

Comment: what are you trying to do? How is the tableview related to the locationManager?

Comment: because my app is dependent on the user's exact location, or it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: @rmp the table view shows cells that are generated with the user's location as a parameter, so it's important to have the location known first.

Comment: Ok, first load an empty table then place a location validation check in the locationManager delegate, once the location is valid, reload the tableview.

Comment: @rmp how could i check if core location is giving me valid coordinates?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: There is a useful api on CLLocationCoordinate2D "CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()" you can then pass that into your location.coordinate to determine if the location is valid. Note: that the coordinate (x: 0, y: 0) is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first load an empty table then place a location validation check in the locationManager delegate, once the location is valid, reload the tableview. Here is a simple example:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let newLocation = locations.last

    let timeDiff = newLocation?.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

    if timeDiff < 5 && (newLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!<=self.accuracyNeeded{



        //stop updating location & heading
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()

        //set currentUserLocation
        Model.sharedInstance.currentUserLocation=newLocation?.coordinate

        //Update tableview here            

        //remove delegate
        self.locationManager?.delegate = nil

    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the second part of the if statement? what does accuracyNeeded stands for?

Comment: `accuracyNeeded` is just a  `var` that contains the level of accuracy of a coordinate value, measured in meters.This can be replaced with a hard-coded value if you want of type `CLLocationAccuracy`.

Comment: Also, `CLLocationAccuracy` is just a `Double`